# Set New Window Size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way I can set the size to a new window in tkinter?

I have tried searching for answers but only found out how to set the size for the main window but not a new window.

```
def open():
   top = Toplevel(bg = "yellow")
   label = Label(top, text = "Password: ", bg = "yellow").pack()
```

Comment: top.geometry('00x00')

Comment: all window share the same methods.